# Как оптимизировать sympy для алгебраической системы?

Tags: sympy

Хотелось получить аналитическое выражение для r(a,b,c). Тесты с числовыми параметрами проходят. А аналитическое решение не удается найти. Если какие-то варианты оптимизации работы подобного кода?

```
from sympy import *

#a=9/2
#b=6
#c=4
#r=29/2

#r,h,x,y,p,q,m,n=symbols('r,h,x,y,p,q,m,n')
r,h,x,y,p,q,m,n,a,b,c=symbols('r,h,x,y,p,q,m,n,a,b,c')

#equation
eq1=h*x-r*a
eq2=h*p-r*b
eq3=h*m-r*c

eq4=(x-h)**2+y**2-(r-a)**2
eq5=(p-h)**2+q**2-(r-b)**2
eq6=(m-h)**2+n**2-(r-c)**2


eq7=(x-p)**2+(y-q)**2-(a+b)**2
eq8=(m-p)**2+(n-q)**2-(c+b)**2

print('solution start')

answ=solve([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5,eq6,eq7,eq8],(r,h,x,y,p,q,m,n))
print(answ)
```

Comment: И всё же не очень понятно, что именно вы хотите. Поясните.

Comment: Варианты назвваются - [maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/), [octave](https://octave.org/) - это программные пакеты для символьной математики.

Comment: Хотелось бы получить конкретную  формулу  для r(a,b,c). Остальные неизвестные h,x,y... также зависят от параметров a,b,c - но они не особо интересуют.  Например если бы у нас было  одно уравнение вида ах^2+bx+c=0 то искомая формула -  это известная формула для корней квадратного уравнения.

Comment: Почему вы думаете что есть формула для решения? Большинство систем не разрешимы в виде аналитической формулы.